# Scraping from inner class

Tags: python-2.7, lxml

I want to scrape definition from Merriam Webster Dictionary. Ex. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abandon

This is the code snippet that I want to scrape.

```html
<div class="definition-block def-text">
        <ul class="definition-list no-count">
                      <li>
              <p class="definition-inner-item">
                <span><span class="intro-colon">:</span> to leave and never return to (someone who needs protection or help)</span>
              </p>
            </li>
                      <li>
              <p class="definition-inner-item">
                <span><span class="intro-colon">:</span> to leave and never return to (something)</span>
              </p>
            </li>
                      <li>
              <p class="definition-inner-item">
                <span><span class="intro-colon">:</span> to leave (a place) because of danger</span>
              </p>
            </li>
                  </ul>
      </div>
```

Here's my code

```
for element in soup.find(class_="definition-list no-count"):
    if(soup.find("li")):
        print element
```

The output is

```html
<li>
<p class="definition-inner-item">
<span><span class="intro-colon">:</span> to leave and never return to (someone who needs protection or help)</span>
</p>
</li>


<li>
<p class="definition-inner-item">
<span><span class="intro-colon">:</span> to leave and never return to (something)</span>
</p>
</li>


<li>
<p class="definition-inner-item">
<span><span class="intro-colon">:</span> to leave (a place) because of danger</span>
</p>
</li>
```

But I want the definition inside the `<span>`. If I use get_text() method I get a type error.

```
for element in soup.find(class_="definition-list no-count"):
        if(soup.find("li")):
            print soup.get_text(element)
```

The output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape.py", line 18, in <module>
    print soup.get_text(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/element.py", line 852, in get_text
    strip, types=types)])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: and your code for this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using beautifulsoup for this task? I'm sure you could do it other ways, but with beautifulsoup it's trivial:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
r = urllib.urlopen('http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abandon').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
definitions = soup.find_all("p", class_="definition-inner-statement")
```

and then you could do with definitions as you require.

Comment: I didn't actually TRY the exact code I gave you, so it's possible there's an error somewhere, but the general point I was making was to use beautifulsoup. It's presumptuous to expect people on the internet just to write out your entire program for you.